# how to set a text for a group in vis.js using groupTemplate

Tags: reactjs, vis.js

I have an application and using vis.js to build timeline events.
I'm using React.
I want to add an icon near each event, so I using groupTemplate and I want to render there a component with group text and icon.
in the options I add:

```
groupTemplate: (item, element) => {
    if (!item) return;
        ReactDOM.render(<TimelineGroupComp item={item}/>, element);
}
```

TimelineGroupComp component render function:

```
return (
     <div className="primary-wrapper" key={this.props.item.content}>
           <div style="background-image:url(../images/myIcon.svg);"/>
     </div>
);
```

I get the correct Icon but the text is the item.id instead item.content.

I try to add a span with the correct text in the TimelineGroupComp but it renders also the item.id, not only the correct text.

Also I have another problem: when I collapse/expaned the group, I have an error in the console:
   Warning: render(...): It looks like the React-rendered content of this
   container was removed without using React. This is not supported and will
   cause errors. Instead, call ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode to empty a 
   container.
and the group is render normal, ignored my component.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is almost a year old, but I thought I'd post the answer to this question anyways for anyone who gets the same issue in the future. I've had the same issue and this is how I fixed it.

Starting with React 16, if you want to use React templates in Vis Timeline you'll have to use `React.createPortal` in the `groupTemplate` option, see https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/.

For the code above, the correct `groupTemplate` would be:

```
groupTemplate: (item, element) => {
  if (!item) return;
  ReactDOM.createPortal(
    ReactDOM.render(<TimelineGroupComp item={item}/>, element),
    element
  )
}
```